# Clustring haproxy + Apache + MySQL

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mysql

Im new to clustering, So I started my LAB using linux centos, My schema is : 2 Load balancers, 2 Web servers (apache), 2 MySQL DBs (separated).

I configured the 2 LBs and 2 Webs, the load balancing works like a charm using the ipvsadm, keepalived and haproxy and GlusterFS.

Right now I get to the DBs, I install MySQL and configured the hearthbeat and DRBD, I tested its works fines.

My question is how to connect the Webs to the DBs, I did some tests using the MySQL user, But I'm not sure. How can I finish my setup so I can have a HA Cluster?

Thank you for your help, any pertinent information are welcome.

Comment: The question is alas too broad. What's your specific issue? Please provide config settings you're having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

You can load balance MySQL with HAproxy.  In a production situation, you would typically have an external LB tier and an internal LB tier in front of the database.  For a test lab, there's no reason you can't run it all on the same HAproxy instances.